# Getting error while decrypting data through AES/ECB/PKCS7 algorithm - "Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm"

Tags: c#, encryption

Code used by me with live data has been provided below

```
public static string AES_Decrypt()
{
    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String("JDUBE1qtuJFSJnGfAFiVtIvwdmDSBoD+NCcxsG3nCaulMS3EtiMYU3A9ovaQQE8y");
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("XW+iCbusaH3g+LOFJWkHu1iaKiRLePCt4lWSWc3h1s4=");
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, null))
    {
        byte[] dest = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
        decrypt.Dispose();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest);
    }
}
```

I am getting error of : 'Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.'

Comment: The key must be Base64 encoded to be 32 bytes in size.

Comment: is key 256 bytes or a different size?  Padding adds random characters to a key to make fix size.  If your key is less than 256 you may want to try with padding turned off.

Comment: When the ciphertext is decrypted with the Base64 encoded key, a final block of 16 0x10 values results. This looks like PKCS7 padding and indicates that the key is correct, otherwise the probability for such a block would be low. However, the plaintext does not seem to be UTF8 decodable.